# Selecting capacitor for SEPIC converter

Tags: capacitor, sepic, ripple-current

I'm looking for an advice how to select capacitors for my SEPIC converter. I have done calculations, but I haven't find Cin, Cs and Cout yet. What seems like a problem is that there are few work papers that recommends to use capacitor "capable to endure calculated current ripple". How can I be sure that the selected capacitor would endure calculated current ripple? I know that ESR is what produces heat in capacitor, but how should I know if some ESR won't produce enough heat to overheat my capacitor? For example, I got that RMS current for an input capacitor is 2.2A, and some voltage ripple condition tells me that the capacitance of that input capacitor must be greater than 180uF. So I'm having a problem how to choose those current capable capacitors on my own. Can someone helps me?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I be sure that the selected capacitor would endure calculated current ripple?

Many capacitor vendors will specify the maximum ripple in their datasheets.

For example, in this datasheet from Kemet, the maximum ripple current (for 105 C ambient at 100 kHz) is given in the "RC" column:

[image]

If you have a ripple voltage requirement, you will have to determine the ripple current from the capacitance value and a little calculus (\$I=C\frac{dV}{dt}\$).

Instead of choosing a badly specified part from EBay, choose one with a proper datasheet, so that you can be sure the specifications meet your requirements.

> I know that ERS is what produces heat in capacitor, but how should I know if some ERS won't produce enough heat to overheat my capacitor?

This will depend on the ambient temperature around the capacitor, how it's mounted to the PCB, etc.

So be sure you understand what conditions the vendor used to specify maximum ripple, and if your specifications are more strenuous (higher ambient temperature, poorer heat sinking), de-rate the part appropriately.

Comment: Well I need 200uF capacitor that can endure ripple current of 2.2A at 100kHz, but I couldn't find any capacitor like that

Comment: @Marc, you might need to use several smaller caps in parallel. 10 22-uF caps, with 220 mA ripple current capability, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Capacitors without specified ripple current are unsuitable for the application without qualifying them yourself. Not the best prospect - as that would take buying a batch of them, running them at full load, and seeing how long they will last while retaining sufficient capacitance.

There may not be a single capacitor that fulfills all the parameters at once: the capacitance, the working voltage, and the ripple current. You may need to parallel lower ripple current parts. Derating the ripple current is a wise thing to do - at least by 25%, ideally by 50%, and for "crazy long life" designs even as much as 80%.